# Sending mass notifications with signalR and hangfire, saving server resources

Tags: c#, entity-framework, signalr, hangfire

I'm programming a SignalR push notification system that uses a hangfire task to push notifications to all the users, lets assume i have 10,000 users and i want to notify them when their account is one month old in the website, what would be more efficient?  Assigning one scheduled task per user to be executed one month after the registration or having a Hangfire task that runs daily and finds me the users that have one month old accounts and notify them.

The task to assign to hangfire will be the following:

- Deactivate inactive profiles and send an email telling the user their account has been deactivated.
- Close posts or inquiries that been inactive for x amount of time and notify them via notification
- The system should be able to find top 10 posters and notify them via email and website notification they have been selected to have extra benefits.
- The task will notify in real time every hour to all the users what was their best score for that week.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution sounds extremely complex for something as simple as this. Are all of these users online all the time? So do you really need to use SignalR for this? Or even Hangfire?

Normally you would do it like this, when user loads a page check if account is over month old and show notification in the UI. Or is there are a reason you can't do it like this?

Comment: Oh that was just one example of one notification i have to do, the users will be online for about  5 hours approximately and they have to get the notifications in real time (that's why i use SignalR), the hangfire part is because we want to schedule first long processes about the users then notify about them, i could just do a request but the request could take a while and the user.

Comment: Maybe you could add all notifications you need to do to your question. For notification if user's account is over month old, does user really care if that message is only triggeted when user loads the page or connects with SignalR? Worst case is that they get that notification next time they connect.

Comment: Yeah you are right, i'll list all the specifications then will form a more concrete question, thank you.